# how to integrate akka actors with decline

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http, scala-cats

I have an application with akka, akka http, and akka streams, so it is not rest or microservice is a ephemeral app; it is a data extractor from a rest api and the app writes to a postgres db,  and it works just i have a doubt , if it is correct to integrate decline and akka in this way.

code :

```
object App extends CommandIOApp(name = "app" , header = "extractor", version = "0.1.0") {

 
  val config = Config( token, jdbcDriver = jdbcDriver, jdbcURL = jdbcURL, jdbcUser = jdbcUser, jdbcPassword = jdbcPassword, jdbcSchema = jdbcSchema)

  override def main: Opts[IO[ExitCode]] =
    Opts.subcommand(name="extract-teams", help="Extract Teams from API"){

      val tableName = Opts.option[String]("recursive", short="r", help="Recursive Extraction")
      val outputFile = Opts.option[Path]("output", short="o", help="Output file").withDefault(Paths.get("output.csv"))

      ( tableName, outputFile).mapN{( table, output) =>
        println(table)
        println(output)

        ClickUpExtractions.extractTeams()

        IO(ExitCode.Success)
      }
    }

  object ClickUpExtractions extends ActorGlobalImplicits {

    def extractTeams(): Unit ={

      import com.arkondata.extractors.ClickUpTeamsActions._
      val extractorFetcher = system.actorOf(ClickUpTeamsFetcher.props(config), name = "EngineActor")
      val extractorWriter = system.actorOf(ClickUpTeamsBulk.props(config) , name = "Writer")

      extractorFetcher ! Fetch(extractorWriter)

    }

  }

}
```

receive code:

```
override def receive: Receive = {
    case WritePG(teamsData) =>
      println("-------writer")
      println(teamsData)
      val teamsPG: List[Teams] = teamsData.map(data => Teams(data.id, data.name, data.color, data.avatar))
      println(teamsPG)

      println("insert-----------------------")
      //// manejar exception aqui  importante!!!
      val upsertStatement = "insert into Teams (id, name, color, avatar) values ( ? , ? , ? , ?) ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET name = EXCLUDED.name"
      BulkWriter(config).insertMany[Teams](teamsPG,upsertStatement).unsafeRunSync()//.unsafeToFuture()//.unsafeRunSync()
      //// manejar exception aqui  importante!!!
      println("insert doobie")
      println("end------------------------")

      self ! "mensaje salida myself!!!!"
    case msg:String =>
      println(msg)
      context.system.terminate()
      System.exit(1) // this is the last step in the akka flow
  }
```

note:

```
System.exit(1) // this is the last step in the akka flow
```

also i use other libraries like doobie, decline, cats: https://ben.kirw.in/decline/effect.html .
The applications works just i need to know if it is correct or if exists a better integration between akka and this : `IO(ExitCode.Success)`

is there any way to get from akka a tell response and validate it, something like :

```
val res = extractorFetcher ! Fetch(extractorWriter)
if (validate(res)) 
   IO(ExitCode.Success)
else 

   IO(ExitCode.Error)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Akka ecosystem relies on `Future`. Cats Effect relies on some `F[_]` - the build-in is `IO` but there are also Monix's `Task` and ZIO.

Translation Future <=> IO can be done like:

```
io.unsafeToFuture

IO.fromFuture(IO(start future here)) // Future start is side-effect on its own
```

Similarly for Monix:

```
task.runToFuture // requires Scheduler

Task.deferFuture(future thunk) // or
Task.deferFutureAction(implicit scheduler => future)
```

If you are using tagless then it's:

```
Async.fromFuture(Sync[F].delay(start future)) // requires implicit Async[F]

val runToFuture: F ~> Future // AFAIR there is no popular type class for it
runToFuture(io)
```

If you are are using streams then there is [streamz](https://github.com/krasserm/streamz) library that handles Akka Streams <=> FS2 translations. Akka Streams, Monix's Observable implements, and FS2 provide an implementation for Reactive Streams so you could make these libraries talk to each other using RS interfaces, so libraries like streamz are just a convenience tools.

There are no other integrations AFAIK and there is no need for them.

However, I would recommend getting some basic knowledge how Akka and Future work (eagerness, memoization, Execution Contexts etc) vs how Cats Effect work (usually laziness, no memoization, no EC besides initialization of `Clock` or `ContextShift` in CE IO, slight differences between CE IO and Monix e.g. Scheduler). If you don't know the difference between them you can easily do some damage.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

1. You can use Akka with other cats based frameworks, but you will have two different jargons in your application : Fibers, ActorSystems, Futures vs IO effects, ... So, if you want to work with Cats go for Monix or FS2, they connect directly with Cats effects. Instead, if Akka is mandatory for you, use Akka Streams, it has a wonderful suite and deal only with Akka distpatchers and Scala Futures.
2. Use Akka Typed. Akka has improved a lot since Akka Typed became production ready. You are creating async computations in the receive function, something prone to errors.